# Cross projects call hiearachy in IntellJ

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I make the call-hiearchy `CTRL+ALT+h` in IntellJ to cross-project, i.e. when I have multiple projects open at the same time.

Example:

```
Project A:

  public class Foo{
    public object foo(){}
  }

Project B:


  public class Bar{
    public object bar(){
       // use Foo:foo 
     }
  }
```

In this example Project B depends on Project A via a maven dependency. I have both projects open in IntellJ and would like to find the dependency in Project B when searching the call hiearchy of `foo` in Project A.

So far IntellJ tells me that `foo` has no dependencies which is wrong given the scope I am looking at. I tried to change the scope in the "hiearchy-callers" window to include both projects but that didn't help.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the IntelliJ code analysis features work cross-project. The correct way to achieve what you need is to configure your project so that Project A and Project B are both modules of the same project (displayed in the same frame).